# Is the following a good/accurate definition for an enumerator (a kind of Turing machine)?

Tags: computational-complexity, computability, turing-machines

I am working a bit with a book from Sipser (Introduction to the theory of computation, 3rd Ed.).

On page 187 in exercise 3.4 one is asked to give a "..formal definition of an enumerator.[..]"

Is the following ok/correct?

Let $A$ be a recursive enumerable language over alphabet $\Sigma$.

(That would be, as I understood, $A \subset \Sigma^*$, and there is a TM $M_A$ such that for all $a \in \Sigma^*$:

$a\in A $ if and only if $M_A$ accepts $a$.)

Let $E_A$ be a TM with 2 tapes. Then:

We call $E_A$ an *enumerator of the language $A$* if and only if

for all $a \in \Sigma^*$: ($a \in A$ if and only if $a$ will eventually appear on the second tape.)

Thank you

Comment: This sounds ok to me, but it's not much more formal than saying something like "it computes a surjective map $\mathbb{N}\to A$". I guess it depends on how much formal you want to be.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Yes, I think it should be possible to define it that way, but if I understood correctly the map would have to be restricted on the subset of the strings that the machine accepts. At least as Sipser introduces Turing machines they always run on strings, not on natural numbers. But this may depend on the presentation, so that in the right context the function could actually be defined on the natural numbers, as you mentioned..

Comment: I am not familiar with Sipser's book, but there is a close connection between TMs and functions $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ (basically you just have to fix a way to code numbers on the tape), so that you use the notation you are more comfortable with. Actually, since there is a (canonical) bijection $\mathbb{N}\to \Sigma^*$, for a countable alphabet $\Sigma$, talking about maps between (finite) strings and maps between natural numbers is essentially the same thing,

Comment: I see...yes, makes sense, I think I remember also in a book from Cutland about Computability using functions on the natural numbers...